# How to hide the status lines of other opened buffers in vim?

Tags: vim, vimrc

The image below illustrates the lines or window titles at the bottom:

[image]

I wonder how to hide the status lines of other opened buffers in vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that those *are* other buffers, but your problem appears to be that you have multiple *windows* open.

A window can display a buffer. A single window can switch between multiple buffers, so you only need one. See [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html) for an overview of windows and buffers.

A window is created when you split the screen using the [split](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:split) commands `:sp` (for horizontal) or `:vsp` for vertical. Instead open files for edit using `:e <filename>`. This will open `<filename>` in a new buffer without creating a new window.

You can list open buffers with `:ls` and switch between them (without creating new windows) using `:bn` and `:bp`. For an overview on how to use buffers, see [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#buffer-hidden).

Comment: I normally open files using :Browse ; then gf to go to file, how can I use this to open the files/buffers  in the same window

Comment: Sadly, when I try `:Browse` I get `E492: Not an editor command: Browse`. Have you got a plugin that offers this? Personally, I'd suggest using the standard file open method: namely `:e`, but that's only my preference.

Comment: I guess you're right `:browse oldfiles` has the same behavior of :e

Comment: here is the command : `:command! Browse :99new +setl\ buftype=nofile | 0put =v:oldfiles | nnoremap <buffer> <CR> :e <C-r>=getline('.')<CR><CR>` I'm afraid I don't know how to change it

Comment: ok instead of :99new i changed it to :tabnew and it works , thanks

Comment: So, how do you remove the status lines from those other "windows"?

Comment: @trusktr: if you want to remove all status lines, you can :set laststatus=0 (see :he laststatus). I can't see a way to remove all status' bar the one on the active window, however. Creating a new question will get you more answers.